# Singularity keeps getting errors when trying to install TF2

Tags: docker, tensorflow, singularity-container

I am trying to make a new Singularity using a recipe but it keeps failing. I have it linked to my github so when I commit it it will automatically be built and compile so that part works fine. However it keep giving me an error like this.

```
 pip3 install -U keras tensorflow-gpu/bin/sh: 2: pip3: not found
 ABORT: Aborting with RETVAL=255Image failed to build: build end 80 seconds.Return value of 1.End Time: Tue Dec 24 02:52:44 UTC 2019.
```

I have tried various things but cant see to get it to work. Here is my recipe file I am sure there is something wrong with that.

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter

%runscript
    exec echo "Tensorflow GPU container"

%files

%environment
    export SSL_CERT_FILE="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
    export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
    export LANG=C.UTF-8

%labels

%post

    pip3 install -U keras tensorflow-gpu
    pip3 install boto3
    pip3 install awscli
    pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
    pip3 install tensorlayer
    pip3 install click
    pip3 install tqdm
    pip3 install easydict
    pip3 install autopep8
    pip3 install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions && jupyter contrib nbextension install
    pip3 install Pillow
    pip3 install numpy
    pip3 install Pillow
    pip3 install matplotlib
    apt-get update
    apt-get -y install python3-tk
    apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6
```

Oh I am posting this to the https://singularity-hub.org site

here is the actual post
https://singularity-hub.org/collections/3942

**Update:**

So this works. But I also need the other libs. how do I install them?

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter

%runscript
    exec echo "Tensorflow GPU container"

%files

%environment
    export SSL_CERT_FILE="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
    export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
    export LANG=C.UTF-8

%labels

%post
    apt-get update
    apt-get install python-pip
    apt-get -y install python3-tk
    apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally got it to work after looking at a lot of others examples

Here is the final recipe file for it

```html
Bootstrap: docker
From: tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0-gpu-py3

%post
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
        unzip \
        git \
        openssl \
        ca-certificates \
        protobuf-compiler \
        && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

    /usr/local/bin/pip3 --no-cache-dir install \
        wheel \
        Pillow \
        opencv-python \
        matplotlib \
        numpy \
        pandas \
        scipy \
        sklearn \
        tqdm \
        argparse \
        boto3 \
        mtcnn \
        Cython \
        contextlib2 \
        lxml \
        easydict \
        kaggle \
        seaborn \
        tensorflow-addons \
        tensorflow-datasets \
        jupyter


%environment
    export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
    export LANG=C.UTF-8
    export SSL_CERT_FILE="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```